# Create Button Using Provided Code

Tags: buttons

I am trying to create a button that sends a text message. I was given code I just don't know what to do with it. Please Help!

iPhone

```
href = "sms://+15558675309/&body=TextHere"
```

Android

```
href = "sms://+15558675309/?body=TextHere"
```

If you’re wondering, “how can I determine whether they’re using an iPhone or an Android?”

Here ya go:

```
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    if ( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) ) { return 'iOS'; }

    else if ( userAgent.match( /Android/i ) ) { return 'Android'; }

    else { return 'unknown'; }
}
Then you can wrap the above SMS syntax like this:

var message_text = 'Pre-filled message goes here'

if (device == 'iOS') {
 href = "sms://+15558675309/&body=" + encodeURI(message_text);
} 

if (device == 'Android') {
 href = "sms://+15558675309/?body=" + encodeURI(message_text);
}
```

Comment: You want to send an SMS after clicking the button? if so, do you have a panel capable of sending short messages?

Comment: this link automatically opens up an iphone's messaging app:
sms://+15558675309/&body=TextHere

The rest of the code was written to determine which device the website visitor is using. I am trying to make this into a button.

Answer (score 0):

To make a clickable button that would open a new windows using your provided link, copy and paste this script to your footer :

```
<script>
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    if ( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) ) { return 'iOS'; }

    else if ( userAgent.match( /Android/i ) ) { return 'Android'; }

    else { return 'unknown'; }
}

var message_text = 'Pre-filled message goes here'
if (device == 'iOS') {
 href = "sms://+15558675309/&body=" + encodeURI(message_text);
} else {
 href = "sms://+15558675309/?body=" + encodeURI(message_text);}

document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = '<button onclick="window.open(' + href + ');">Click me!</button>';
</script>
```

Then, create a `div` element and set it's ID to `myElement` or anything you want, like : 
`<div id="myElement"></div>`.

After loading the page, the button will inserted to your `div`.

Comment: It needs to be able to recognize the device the visitor is using. That is what the rest of the provided code is for.

Comment: @JavierPeña You already have a function that does that. Use this button at the end of your code, and it will create a button depending on whether the visitor is using iPhone or Android.

Comment: Where do I put the function?

Comment: I updated the answer for you.

Comment: Dude Im so freaking confused.. can we talk on the phone or something?

Comment: I've updated the answer again. Just copy and paste the entire script to your footer (delete the old script). Then, add `<div id="myElement"></div>` to the place that you want your button. If it didn't work again, then we can talk.